# Angularjs ng-repeat show message in Onclick section

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show some message in current section when I click update link but I'm seeing the message in all sections. How can I do in Angularjs data-ng-repeat? I don't want use JQuery.

View:

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="item in $scope.items">
                                {{item.name}}
                            <input type="number" data-ng-value="0" />
                                <span>{{$scope.ErrorMessage}}</span>
                            </div>
<button ng-click="save()">click</button>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.save= function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
                            svc.update(item[i])
                                        .then(function (data) {
                                            $scope.customer = data;
                                        })
                                        .catch(function (error) {
                                           $scope.ErrorMessage="not updated"
                                        });
}
```

I'm saving ng-repeat data on single click. Each section is its own API call.If any call is failed to save the data I need to show message on below that section.

Comment: some codes would help debug easily and provide you with better explanation.

Comment: I've added sample code

Comment: You seem to not understand a lot of the concepts that angular has. I would advise you to go and do some more learning of the directives and basic angular functionality because the sample code you have provided is all over the place.

Comment: Just to give you a little direction look into ng-click (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and review some of the principles of ng-repeat (looping) as well as some data structures to relate to what you want to do.

Comment: your binding for the view of repeat and click and maybe everything is wrong, rather posts what is in the controller the whole. and the view. :)

Comment: May be I gave the wrong sample code:). I'm saving ng-repeat data onclick. Each section is its own API call.If any call is failed to save I need to show message on that section.

Comment: item in $scope.items is all wrong. If you are binding $scope.items in controller then items is enough.i.e, item in items. furthermore, you don't declare a click function in class. Angular has something like ng-click for that. So ng-click="dynamicmessage()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.items = ['bulk update 02 Mar', 'bulk update 03 Mar'];
  $scope.errorMessages = [];
  
  $scope.save = function () {
    
   // you can use your save logic here instead of angular.forEach
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item, key) {
       $scope.errorMessages[key] = "Error occurred";
    });
    
     
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Description</td>
          <td>Process</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td>{{item}}</td>
          <td>{{errorMessages[$index]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If button is outside of data-ng-repeat how can I show message?

Comment: Hi, Now my button is inside of ng-repeat. I want to show some data if I click button. I'm trying to pass index to controller   ng-click="vm.CustomerDisplay(customerDetails.id[$index])" , controller vm.show[index]=true; but not working.

Comment: @user3194721, I guess, you have a problem with this method `vm.CustomerDisplay(customerDetails.id[$index])`; I don't know how your method actually looks like so, its better to post another question for this issue.

Comment: please update and format that question with your controller code, I will respond it tomorrow.

Comment: I've updated my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808005/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-index

Answer (score 0):

There are mistakes in your code. To refer the `variable` in DOM, one shouldn't make use of `$scope`. Only in the *'.js'* file, the `$scope` is used. Plus, the `json` data that your looping in the HTML, has not been provided in the question. So I have assumed one.

Check out the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/roqsy7qg/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.name}}
        <input type="number" data-ng-value="0" />
        <button ng-click="dynamicmessage(item)">click</button>
        <span>{{item.message}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        'name': 'item 1'
    }, {
        'name': 'item 2'
    }, {
        'name': 'item 3'
    }, {
        'name': 'item 4'
    }, ];
    $scope.dynamicmessage = function (obj) {
        obj.message = 'Hi';
    }
});
```

Comment: <button ng-click="dynamicmessage()">click</button> is outside of ng-repeat.

Comment: how can it be outside of the repeat? How are you going to know which item to modify?